# How to add slashes to the end of a TCHAR buffer[] using Win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi, concatenation, slash

I am trying to add two slashes "\" to the end of a TCHAR buffer[] using wsprintf() in my Win32 C++ app.
The variable "buffer" holds a file path: C:\Users\nayub\Desktop\Folder1\Hello. I want to add two slashes to the end of this file path so did the following code:

```
wsprintf(filename_buff, buffer, L"\\");
MessageBox(hWnd, filename_buff, L"New Folder Directory", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

However, the messagebox displays "C" and nothing else. I'm not sure why it is getting "C" and not the file path because before the slashes are added, the file path prints out correctly.

Comment: I am also not sure why it is getting "C". Nothing in your code indicates a reason for that letter. Please provide a [mre] (including declarations for your variables).

Comment: If you received any warnings while compiling please copy/paste those into the question. Chances are you are ignoring one which is telling you precisely what's wrong.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `wsprintf`, especially the format string. If you know the buffer is large enough you could use `wcscat` to append to it. Depending on your project settings you might actually be calling `wsprintfA` which would give the behavior you're describing when passed a wide string.

Comment: Obvious problem: you're using the wrong function. `wsprintf` is a weird Windows thing that's mostly a left-over from Windows 3.x. What you want is almost certainly `swprintf` instead. Next problem: you shouldn't really be fiddling with `TCHAR`, which is another weird Windows thing, in this case left over from Windows 95/98. Your code is solely for wide characters anyway, so use `wchar_t`, not `TCHAR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `wsprintf()` incorrectly. It needs to look more like this instead:

```cpp
wsprintf(filename_buff, L“%s\\”, buffer);
```

Or, you can use [`PathAddBackslash()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathaddbackslashw) instead:

```cpp
wcscpy(filename_buff, buffer);
PathAddBackslash(filename_buff);
```

However, you tagged your question as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), so just use `std::wstring` instead:

```cpp
MessageBox(hWnd, (std::wstring(buffer)+L"\\").c_str(), L"New Folder Directory", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Comment: Or, tags and warnings aside, the OP could be doing a non-Unicode C compile. Then "*the messagebox displays 'C' and nothing else*" indeed.

Comment: @dxiv the code shown by the OP would not compile in a non-Unicode build.

Comment: MSVC at least compiles it as C, with the expected C4133 warnings.

Comment: I used wsprintf() the way you showed in your example and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @dxiv `MessageBox(..., L”New Folder Directory”, ...)` would not compile if `MessageBox()` were mapped to `MessageBoxA()` in a non-Unicode build

Comment: @RemyLebeau Emphasis on **C** compile. MSVC [does it](https://rextester.com/OGVO62028), and gcc [does it](https://godbolt.org/z/TcY8ET) too. I don't mean to argue with the OP that `wsprintf` fixed it, but I don't see how the original code could have displayed a lone `"C"` in the messagebox if not for an ANSI build being passed wide strings. Not that it really matters anyway ;-)